# Drools - fireUntilHalt locks on KnowledgeBase

Tags: multithreading, drools

I have a daemon thread that calls `kieSession.fireUntilHalt`. And facts are inserted from other threads (http).

At some point the 'firing' thread gets into "Waiting" state and never returns. So the other facts inserting threads are blocked on this thread.

**Rule Firing Thread Stack:**

```
at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method) 
at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:186) 
at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.parkAndCheckInterrupt(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:834) 
at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquireQueued(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:867) 
at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquire(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1197) 
at java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantReadWriteLock$WriteLock.lock(ReentrantReadWriteLock.java:945) 
at org.drools.core.common.UpgradableReentrantReadWriteLock.lowPriorityWriteLock(UpgradableReentrantReadWriteLock.java:109) 
at org.drools.core.common.UpgradableReentrantReadWriteLock.writeLock(UpgradableReentrantReadWriteLock.java:95) 
at org.drools.core.impl.KnowledgeBaseImpl.lock(KnowledgeBaseImpl.java:684) 
at org.drools.core.reteoo.builder.PatternBuilder.attachObjectTypeNode(PatternBuilder.java:275) 
at org.drools.core.reteoo.ClassObjectTypeConf. (ClassObjectTypeConf.java:107) 
at org.drools.core.common.ObjectTypeConfigurationRegistry.getObjectTypeConf(ObjectTypeConfigurationRegistry.java:72) 
at org.drools.core.reteoo.AccumulateNode.createResultFactHandle(AccumulateNode.java:149) 
at org.drools.core.phreak.PhreakAccumulateNode.evaluateResultConstraints(PhreakAccumulateNode.java:683) 
at org.drools.core.phreak.PhreakAccumulateNode.doNode(PhreakAccumulateNode.java:89) 
at org.drools.core.phreak.RuleNetworkEvaluator.switchOnDoBetaNode(RuleNetworkEvaluator.java:563) 
at org.drools.core.phreak.RuleNetworkEvaluator.evalBetaNode(RuleNetworkEvaluator.java:534) 
at org.drools.core.phreak.RuleNetworkEvaluator.innerEval(RuleNetworkEvaluator.java:334) 
at org.drools.core.phreak.RuleNetworkEvaluator.outerEval(RuleNetworkEvaluator.java:161) 
at org.drools.core.phreak.RuleNetworkEvaluator.evaluateNetwork(RuleNetworkEvaluator.java:116) 
at org.drools.core.phreak.RuleExecutor.evaluateNetwork(RuleExecutor.java:77) 
- locked [0x00000000fe586af0] (a org.drools.core.phreak.RuleExecutor) 
at org.drools.core.common.DefaultAgenda.evaluateEagerList(DefaultAgenda.java:990) 
- locked [0x000000008ad60cd8] (a java.util.LinkedList) 
at org.drools.core.common.DefaultAgenda.fireNextItem(DefaultAgenda.java:945) 
at org.drools.core.common.DefaultAgenda.fireUntilHalt(DefaultAgenda.java:1190) 
at org.drools.core.impl.StatefulKnowledgeSessionImpl.fireUntilHalt(StatefulKnowledgeSessionImpl.java:1283) 
at org.drools.core.impl.StatefulKnowledgeSessionImpl.fireUntilHalt(StatefulKnowledgeSessionImpl.java:1260) 
at com.comp.narch.lfc.decision.rules.util.FireUntilHaltSpawn.call(FireUntilHaltSpawn.java:21) 
at com.comp.narch.lfc.decision.rules.util.FireUntilHaltSpawn.call(FireUntilHaltSpawn.java:11)
```

**Fact Inserting Thread (blocked) Stack:**

```
at org.drools.core.common.DefaultAgenda.addEagerRuleAgendaItem(DefaultAgenda.java:282) 
- waiting to lock [0x000000008ad60cd8] (a java.util.LinkedList) 
at org.drools.core.reteoo.PathMemory.queueRuleAgendaItem(PathMemory.java:153) 
at org.drools.core.reteoo.PathMemory.doLinkRule(PathMemory.java:120) 
- locked [0x00000000fe586928] (a org.drools.core.reteoo.PathMemory) 
at org.drools.core.reteoo.PathMemory.linkSegment(PathMemory.java:90) 
at org.drools.core.reteoo.SegmentMemory.notifyRuleLinkSegment(SegmentMemory.java:170) 
at org.drools.core.reteoo.LeftInputAdapterNode$LiaNodeMemory.setNodeDirty(LeftInputAdapterNode.java:647) 
at org.drools.core.reteoo.LeftInputAdapterNode.doInsertSegmentMemory(LeftInputAdapterNode.java:277) 
at org.drools.core.reteoo.LeftInputAdapterNode.doInsertObject(LeftInputAdapterNode.java:229) 
at org.drools.core.reteoo.LeftInputAdapterNode.assertObject(LeftInputAdapterNode.java:197) 
at org.drools.core.reteoo.CompositeObjectSinkAdapter.doPropagateAssertObject(CompositeObjectSinkAdapter.java:502) 
at org.drools.core.reteoo.CompositeObjectSinkAdapter.propagateAssertObject(CompositeObjectSinkAdapter.java:387) 
at org.drools.core.reteoo.ObjectTypeNode.assertObject(ObjectTypeNode.java:288) 
at org.drools.core.reteoo.EntryPointNode.assertObject(EntryPointNode.java:251) 
at org.drools.core.common.NamedEntryPoint.insert(NamedEntryPoint.java:367) 
at org.drools.core.common.NamedEntryPoint.insert(NamedEntryPoint.java:286) 
at org.drools.core.impl.StatefulKnowledgeSessionImpl.insert(StatefulKnowledgeSessionImpl.java:1430) 
at org.drools.core.impl.StatefulKnowledgeSessionImpl.insert(StatefulKnowledgeSessionImpl.java:1372) 
at com.comp.narch.lfc.service.impl.DefaultServiceInstanceMgmtServiceImpl.newAppMetric(DefaultServiceInstanceMgmtServiceImpl.java:84)
```

Drools Version - 6.1.0.Final

Comment: 6.1.0 is the first version after a major redesign of the rule engine, so it might be worth trying 6.3.0 Final. - If the problem persists, open a ticket on the Drools bug reporting site.

Comment: @laune, Thank you. I shall try with 6.3.0.Final and update the post

Comment: There is no `UpgradableReentrantReadWriteLock` in v6.3.0 .Final `KnowledgeBaseImpl`. Hope this problem wont raise again :). Thank you @laune.